# How to extract values from a multipolygon that are inside another polygon

Tags: r, polygon, spatial

I have a shapefile with many (quadratic) polygons with values in them.

```
shape 
class       : SpatVector 
 geometry    : polygons 
 dimensions  : 3582951, 5  (geometries, attributes)
 extent      : 388338.5, 610066, 5265156, 5515628  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 source      : xyz.shp
 coord. ref. : ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (EPSG:25832) 
 names       :  OBJECTID VALUE KLASSE     LEGENDE OBJECT_ID
 type        :     <num> <num>  <num>       <chr>     <int>
 values      : 3.585e+06  1.71      4 > 1,5 - 2,0      2290
               3.585e+06 2.665      5 > 2,0 - 3,0      2291
               3.585e+06 2.656      5 > 2,0 - 3,0      2292
```

and a multipolygon with a circular buffer areas

```
buffer500
class       : SpatVector 
 geometry    : polygons 
 dimensions  : 43, 5  (geometries, attributes)
 extent      : 430079, 570836.7, 5298494, 5482076  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 source      : IRMS_trees_buffer500m.shp
 coord. ref. : ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (EPSG:25832) 
 names       : N_total DN15_14    id     x     y
 type        :   <num>   <num> <chr> <num> <num>
 values      :    2.18   -3.67 WR-T1 9.863 47.93
                   2.4   -6.49 WR-T2 9.865 47.93
                  1.89   -6.93 WR-T3 9.866 47.93
```

I want to extract all values of the shape inside every single feature of the buffer vector (43 features in total) and put them with the right id into a data frame.

I know how to extract it for one feature with

```
test <- shape[buffer500[buffer500$id=='WR-T1',]]

df<-as.data.frame(test)
```

```
plot(test)
```

[image: Here are the selected polygons from feature 1]
Has somebody an idea for that in only a few steps?
Cheers